# How to remove shadow from dialog?

Tags: java, android

How to remove it (not black tint)?
[Shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkzKT.jpg)

I tried to clear flags

```java
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

but it only removes the black tint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: it made dialog transparent too